# Prevent body from rotating in Box2D

Tags: java, box2d, game-physics, jbox2d

I am currently using Box2d, more precisely the Java port jBox2d.

I have a circle that is colliding with other circles when falling (all those circles form a kind of a crank, see picture below).

[image: illustration]

Naturely, the circle begins to rotate when falling. But I would like to **prevent it from rotating** so that the friction is much higher.

Comment: I know that, thanks. But we are doing computer science, a physics engine is supposed to allow you to change the standard physics. And I would like my circle not to rotate.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To prevent body from rotating set fixedRotation = true at BodyDef or call setFixedRotation of Body (if you need run-time change behavior).

Comment: Actually, I tried all fixedRotation = true and angularDamping and everything you would imagine on the BodyDef object but nothing worked.
Though, I finally manage to get it working by using setAngularDamping(200) on the body object itself on runtime. I may try setFixedRotation on the body object as well.

Comment: Looks like you doing smth wrong, fixed rotation MUST work. Check density of your fixture, it must be more then zero. I had such trouble because of this thing.

Comment: Using .SetFixedRotation(true) on the Body (not the BodyDef) worked in box2dweb.

Answer (score 4):

In the runtime you want to set set rotationfixed then

```
b2Body body;  
body->SetFixedRotation(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed rotation means rotation at fixed axis in physics,so isFixedRotation=true; may not solve this problem,but setting angular damping to such a high value can prevent from rotating